# node_access() returns FALSE but I can view the node

Tags: 6, users

I got a view which gets rendered to a variable which then gets mailed to the user. A few days ago, I noticed that this functionality is broken (empty mails) and that for the administrator users everything works fine. So the problem got something to do with permissions.

Strangely enough, if I make the view a page normal users can visit it and see it. If the users try the mail feature, the mail is blank.

I tried to write a function which generates the desired output itself.

```
function my_function($node) {
  global $user;
  $output = '';

  if (node_access('view', $node)) {
    $output = 'yeah';
  }
  else if ($node->uid == $user->uid) {
    $output = 'meh';
  }
  else {
    $output = 'nai';
  }

  return $output;
```

}

The output is 'meh'. `node_access('view', $node)` returns `FALSE`. There is no problem for the logged in users to go on the site, and view the node.

I got the Content Access module installed. I configured it to grant every authenticated user access to their own content, and a master-user is allowed to view everybody's content.

I've already rebuild the permissions, but the behavior is the same. Has anyone an explanation how it can be that one can view the node/view without problem and at the same time for the same user [`node_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_access/6) returns `FALSE`?

Comment: Don't you need to pass `$user` into the `node_access` call as the third parameter?

Comment: @LesterPeabody  `$account` is an optional argument.  If empty, it will default the the current $user.

Comment: OK, as I deactivated content-access-module at least node_access() returns true. I still don't get the view I wanna mail. Sadly there's content visible to users that shouldn't. I'll try to take care of that by myself instead of using content-access-module. :(